# Injection of HttpContext related dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to inject `HttpContext` related dependencies in Web API project. I have a `ActionFilterAttribute` which constructs an instance of application specific context from the current HTTP context and then stores it in `Request.Properties` bag:

```
    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IAppContext context = await this.CreateAppContextAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        actionContext.Request.Properties["ctx"] = context;
        .....
    }
```

`IAppContext` is totally isolated from `HttpContext` to make my query handlers work in a host different from Web API. Now I want it to be injected into my handlers:

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public MyModel GetStuff([FromUri ]MyQuery q)
    {
        var handler = ... .Container.Resolve<MyQueryHandler>()
        return handler.Execute(q);
    }
}
```

where `MyQueryHandler` is like this:

```
public class MyQueryHandler {
    private IAppContext ctx;

    public MyQueryHandler(IAppContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

How do I make the container to inject the context from `Request.Properties` bag? I suspect my solution with `ActionFilterAttribute` may cause the trouble but it looks so natural to me.

No dependency to `HttpContext.Current` please.

Comment: Prevent injecting runtime data like `HttpContext` or its properties into your components, as [described here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Thank you! Those are valid arguments, I need to think it over.